# How to get and assign values in current activity by getting values from previous activity using intent in Espresso Junit test case?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I want to assign some values in my current activity by getting values from my previous activity using `intent`. I'm new to espresso, I do not how to achieve this using `Espresso` `JUnit` test case. Could you please suggest me an idea pass intent values from one activity to another activity using JUnit test case in espresso. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Olive, did you got the solution for this? i am also strucked here. please share if you solved.

Comment: @RamKoti I'm sorry not yet found solution for this